# How can I cleanly trim window blinds?

Tags: blinds

I ordered some custom blinds but they are a little too long. How can I cleanly trim through the plastic and fabric?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there any mechanizeum  at the ends?  That would need to be shorten also, making   life more difficult.  The ends need to be taken off and re-glued on.  To cut, a thin fine tooth hand saw or a metal/diamond circuital saw blade should cut with just a bit of sanding after.

Comment: Might need to use scissors for the fabric.

Comment: @crip659 no mechanisms at the ends

Comment: That makes life easier, just the plastic and fibre to cut.  If you can separate the two would make things easy to cut.  Think the fibre needs to be cut differently that the plastic.  Plastic easy to cut with a saw, fibre might catch too much.

Comment: What kind of 'fabric' [I've never seen venetians made of anything other than metal or plastic]. There are usually two alternatives, pop the ends out, then… 1) clamp the whole structure & tape it to prevent movement. Saw it. 2) cut the structural members then get a blind cutter & do each leaf one at a time...